# ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE mime type filters seem completely broken

Tags: android, android-intent, mime-types, intentfilter

I'm currently building an app where I want to handle receiving shared images. Everything worked just fine with the `ACTION_SEND`, with the following declaration

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
</intent-filter>
```

In my manifest, but when I tried to do the same with `ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE`, my share activity started being suggested when sharing mixes of video and images. I dug deeper and found out that the 'mimeType' received is `*/*`, which the OS matches with `image/*`. So I did an experiment and tried the following configuration:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="application/pdf" />
</intent-filter>
```

and wouldn't you know it, my activity started being suggested when selecting images and videos, even though they have nothing to do with PDFs.

What is the intended way to declare my application as being able to receive multiple images, and only images?

Comment: I'm using the built-in camera application. Reading through the doc, it sounds like the appropriate behaviour for a sender is to default to `*/*`, but this means it will match with all receivers that support send multiple, regardless of their mime-type filter